# Power Automate/Sharepoint file - multiple updates, but file locks after first

Tags: excel, power-automate, lock

I'm working on a Power Automate flow for my work. I'm pretty new to it, but I was making headway until I hit this issue.

I have a button in the sharepoint library. It has three key processes

- Copy the folder to another library, then delete the old one (I can't
  use move because the libraries have different columns).
- Email the relevant people for the new folder.
- Update a spreadsheet inside the folder.

The first two work fine. The folder moves, the old one deletes, the email sends. But the update step is the problem.

When it updates, the spreadsheet, it has two tables. One called basic_detail, the other called order_updates. It needs to update a row in basic_detail, and add a row to order_updates (doesn't matter which way round).

But whenever I run the flow, the first one works, but the second then fails with the message:

`Graph API is unable to acquire or refresh a lock on the file because it is already locked.`

I know it's not a case of someone having the file open, as it's a developing process, so the only person who has access to the sharepoint library right now is me.

I initially hoped that checking the file out, doing the edits, and then checking it in would solve it, but it doesn't seem to.

Below is the section of the flow that's causing the problems.

[image: Steps of the flow which are causing the problems]

As I say, I'm still very green to PA (literally used it for the first time 3 weeks ago), so if I'm doing something wildly silly, let me know. Otherwise, any help getting around the lock issue (be it by releasing the lock, performing multiple updates in one step, or anything else) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to check in/check out the files? That could be a potential problem. Also, check out this same question / answer here if you have not already https://coyleonsharepoint.wordpress.com/2020/04/23/ms-flow-giving-graph-api-is-unable-to-acquire-or-refresh-a-lock-on-the-file-because-it-is-already-locked-message-on-excel-file/

Comment: @BeerusDev - no, I don't need to. I mainly added that step because I'd had a similar problem before and hoped check out/in would solve. As to the link, I've read that one (it was actually the one that gave me the check out/in idea), and the only part of it that seemed to apply is the "wait 10 minutes" but because of the process we're running, leaving the file locked for 10 minutes isn't really practical.